# Windows 7 batchfile to iterate through subdirectories selecting first file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am running windows 7 64 bit

I have a directory, full of sub directories, each subdirectory has many files.

I want to write a batchfile which will iterate through the subdirectories in the current directory, copy the first file in each subdirectory to the parent directory, renaming the file .txt

so far I have this:

```
`for /D %%s in (./*) do
(
 cd %%s
 i=1
 for /f %%a in (./*) do
 (
  if i==1
   cp %%a >> ./../%%s.txt
   i=i+1
  else
 ) 
 cd ..
)`
```

All I am getting is that the syntax of the command is incorrect.

I have tried using echos to see how far I get and I am not getting past the first line.

Comment: `(` goes on the same line as `do`

Comment: also, you need to use `set` to set and do math with variables

Comment: I have moved the ( to the same line as the do and added set before i=1 and i=1+1; I still don't get past the first line - I have added an echo above the cd %%s and it is not getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this way is simpler and easier to understand:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /D %%s in (*) do (
   set "firstFile="
   for %%a in ("%%s\*.*") do if not defined firstFile set "firstFile=%%a"
   copy "!firstFile!" "%%s.txt"
)
```

An observation on previous code:

- The `.\anyName` although correct, is usually never used. A dot indicate "current folder" and `.\anyName` indicate the anyName below current folder, that is *exactly the same* than just `anyName`.

**EDIT**: *New method to copy the Nth file*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /D %%s in (*) do (
   set i=0
   for %%a in ("%%s\*.*") do (
      set /A i+=1
      if !i! equ N copy "%%a" "%%s.txt"
   )
)
```

You must write a number in place of `N` above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that works. Is there any way to choose the xth file rather than the first?

Comment: Yes, but that is an _entirely different_ problem! Just include your `i` variable and get the name when `i` is equal to N. Do you want I post the code for this case?

Comment: You're a star; Now, do you know how to change the clutch on an '01 Landrover discovery....

Answer (score 2):

Batch syntax is very specific.

```
for... do (
 whatever

if ... (
 whatever

) else (
 whatever
```

The open-parentheses **must** be in the position indicated. `whatever` may be on the following line or the same line as the `(`

If you have a sequence of statements (for an if-true condition, for example) then these **must** be parenthesised

The close-parenthesis before an `else` must be on the samp physical line as the `else`.

`cp` is invalid - unless you're using cygwin, the command is `copy`

`i=i+1` is invalid - use `set /a i=i+1` (`/a` for arithmetic expressions, else it's assumed to be s string expression)

`%var%` for the value of a variable. `i` will never be equal to `1` **except** within a block statement (parenthesised series of statements) then you need to invoke `delayedexpansion` (an option of `setlocal`) and use `!var!` as `%var%` is resolved to be the value of `var` at the time the expression is **parsed**, not executed.

`/` is a switch indicator, not a directory separator. `\` is a directory-separator. Windows can often make the substitution, but not when there is a syntax ambuity. Best to use the correct character.

"quote" arguments that may contain separators (like spaces.) It's not *strictly* necessary in a `cd` statement, but it's harmless there and is required almost everywhere else.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /D %%s in (.\*) do (
 cd "%%s"
 set /a i=1
 for /f %%a in (.\*) do (
  if !i!==1 (
   cOpY %%a >> ".\..\%%s.txt"
   set /a i=i+1
  ) else (     ) 
 cd ..
)
```

Although... I'd be tempted to use `PUSHD "%%s"` in place of the first `cd` and `popd` for the second.

Not sure what your `copy` is aimed at achieving. To append to an existing file, I'd use `type`. There *is* a `copy` syntax that implements `append this file to that` but I use it so rarely I'd have to look it up.

*commandname* /?

from the prompt will provide (sometimes obscure) documentation.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to solve a business problem where I have a directory full of subdirectories, each with the name of a colleague. Each subdirectory has a number of pictures of the colleague. I need to copy a picture of each colleague to the parent directory, renaming the file so I have a single, appropriately named picture of each colleague.

Your code has helped me get past the first couple of hurdles. I am getting command line output from running your code of setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Comment: ) was unexpected at this time

I have tried adding a parenthesis where I expected one was needed, before the cd .. and this has not changed the output

Comment: I have moved the brackets so they are in the right place and the code now runs, which is awesome, however, I am getting the response that the system cannot find the file ./*